# How can I expand already built rooms?

Tags: prison-architect

If I build foundations connecting to the existing room and remove the partitioning wall, the space where the division-wall was is "outside".

Comment: Dear SE user: Note that since this game is an Alpha, the developent cycle should have made this question obsolete by the time you read it. It is already one year old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view.php?id=74) (link leads to internal bugtracker), due to a missing check for the space where the wall used to be.

Quoting from the bug report, there is a workaround:

> 1. Make building foundation.
> 2. Make another building foundation adjacent to it
> 3. This will, correctly, remove one of the otherwise double walls.
> 4. Use foundation demolish to remove the interior wall.
> 5. Leaves unusable outside area inside.
>
> The work-around is to replace step 4 with:
>   4. Build concrete floor material along length of inside wall, which correctly labels the area as interior.

Answer (score 0):

One part of the issue is now solved, which is done by what is noted above. Even though it would be neat to create a building outside of the other building, without having to do these tricks: Make the building **end atleast one row inside the wall of the building you're trying to connect it with.** Note that this will cost you additional money, since it will be like you're building the new building PLUS the space inside the old building => try to calculate the space you need the first time around you build it, in order to save money.

This is of course hard to work around when you're expanding, but quite crucial initially trying to make the economy work when you start off with a new prison.